# Web Crawling - Cannot Find the Data Table from HTML and XHR Code

Tags: python, pandas, xmlhttprequest

[https://www.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::24|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::15%3Ename_trans;1](https://www.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::24%7Csector::a%7Cindustry::a%7CequityType::a%7Cexchange::15%3Ename_trans;1)

I was trying to crawl the table with 50 stocks on this page using python, maybe pandas or BeautifulSoup module, together with the underlying hyperlink attached to each company name on the first column of the table.

As I check its HTML code, I cannot find the company names nor company ticker, such as "Agillic" and "AGILC", so I thought they might come from an Ajax call.

However, as I open Chrome devtools and check XHR, it appears to me that the data does not originate from XHR too.

Then I go ahead and try pandas read_html function to read for tables on the page, somehow the data can be read and whole table crawled (I don't understand how pandas do that)! But even so, with this method I cannot get the underlying hyperlink from the first column of company names, so the method is still not good enough in my case.

Can anyone inspire me where exactly is the table hiding and if there are any methods for me to crawl the table together with the underlying hyperlinks at the same time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, When the data is dynamically loaded by JS, you can make benefits of `Selenium` library to catch the contents.

Comment: hi @Pooria_T I just tried with Selenium as you mentioned too on the site, afterwards I use BeautifulSoup to extract all "a" links but still the links are missing. not sure why... You can have a try too?

Comment: i just tried again, a seeming solution is to include a time.sleep(X) function into the code and hence allow Selenium time to load the full code... seemingly.

Comment: Could you fix it with `sleep()`?